# Probability tree diagram problem

Tags: probability

In a woman single badminton match, the first player who wins two out of three sets win the match. The probability of a particular player winning a set is 0.7 if she has won the previous set. The probability of the player winning a set is 0.4 if she lost the previous set.

(a) Find the probability that the player wins the match given that she lost the first set.
0.7*0.4 = 0.28

I just need help on question a. This is very simple but I am still confused on the concept of tree diagram mix with conditional probability. Its only a 2 marks problem but I got confused when I see the solution to this problem. Basically they just find the product of the probability (win given lose) and (win and win given lose). Can someone enlighten me why calculating the probability of winning the match is possible without knowing the probability of losing the first set? Thanks

Comment: Does this make sense?  If $A$ is playing $B$ and $A$ wins the first set, then you're saying that $A$ has a $.7$ probability of winning set two and $B$ has a $.4$ probability of winning set two...but $.7+.4>1$.

Comment: By drawing the three diagram, if player A won the first set, she will have 0.7 probability of winning the second set and 0.3 of not winning the second set. But if player A lose the first set, she will have 0.4 probability of winning the second set and 0.6 of losing the second set. Adding 0.7 and 0.4 if false since 0.7 is when the player win the previous match and 0.4 is when the player lose the first match. For this problem you will need the help of a tree diagram

Comment: Oh, are you saying that these numbers only apply to one player, say $A$?

Comment: If that is the case, then yes.  having lost the first set, the only way for $A$ to win the match is to win the next two sets. The probability that $A$ wins set two is $.4$, because she lost set one.  Then, trusting that she wins set two, the probability that she also wins set three is $.7$ so the probability that $A$ wins both sets two and three, having lost set one, is the product $.4\times .7$

Comment: I see thank you for the explanation. Its not hard to understand but once I applied the conditional probability formula into the problem, I got confused since we need to know the probability of losing the first set.